# No puedo centrar elementos de form HTML

Tags: html, html5, css, bootstrap

Estoy con algo sencillo, pero que por alguna razon no puedo lograr. Como dice el titulo, no puedo centrar los elementos de un formulario HTML. Queria ver si me podian dar una mano. Aca el codigo:

```
<body>
    <object id="header" data="header.html" onload="resizeObj(this);"></object>

            <form id="formulario" action="enviado.php" method="post">
                <div id="content">
                    <label>Nombre</label><br>
                    <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" /> <br>
                    <label>Email</label><br>
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" /> <br>
                    <label>Contenido</label><br>
                    <textarea id="contenido" name="comment" cols="30" rows="5">Ingresa aqui el mensaje...</textarea><br>

                    <input id="campo3" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
                </div>
            </form>

     <object id="footer" data="footer.html" onload="resizeObj(this);" ></object>
</body>
```

Y el css:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border:none;
    width: 100%;
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#formulario{
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-content: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    width: 500px;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 14px;
}

input {
    font-size: 14px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #777;
    max-width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    padding: 7px 8px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    background: #0088B2;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

textarea{
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #777;
    max-width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    padding: 7px 8px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #444;
}
```

Aca una captura de como queda el sitio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creo que estás usando la propiedad incorrecta, la que necesitas en este caso para el formulario es **[text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)** en vez de **[align-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content)** (la cual es una propiedad de un contenedor flexbox):

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border:none;
    width: 100%;
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#formulario{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <object id="header" data="header.html" onload="resizeObj(this);"></object>

            <form id="formulario" action="enviado.php" method="post">
                <div id="content">
                    <label>Nombre</label><br>
                    <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" /> <br>
                    <label>Email</label><br>
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" /> <br>
                    <label>Contenido</label><br>
                    <textarea id="contenido" name="comment" cols="30" rows="5">Ingresa aqui el mensaje...</textarea><br>

                    <input id="campo3" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
                </div>
            </form>

     <object id="footer" data="footer.html" onload="resizeObj(this);" ></object>
</body>
```

Comment: OMG. Que noob lo mio jaja. Muchas gracias, con eso anduvo :)
Tengo que esperar unos minutos para marcarla como respuesta correcta. Gracias! ;)

Comment: no te preocupes hermano, aquí todos aprendemos siempre y compartimos con la mejor de las intenciones :D dale con todo el power 2.0!

Comment: @FacundoCurti considera marcar ésta respuesta como correcta.

Comment: Agradezco el comentario por el voto negativo.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría también otras dos soluciones.

La primera es agregar un padding al formulario y agregar un 100% de ancho a los elementos input, no centraría pero daría una muy buena apariencia.

```
form {
  padding: 30px;
}

form input, form textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/ttbeobLm/

La segunda opción es similar, pero agregando un contenedor dentro del form,
agregarle un ancho al contenedor, y centrarlo.

```
form {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
form .content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

form input, form textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/ttbeobLm/1/

Comment: Conversación trasladada a [sala de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50799/discussion-between-luiggi-mendoza-and-alejandrojsr7).

Answer (score 1):

```
#formulario{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pon el formulario dentro de un div con una clase y le pones float none

```
<div class="centrar-form">
  <form>tus formularios</form>
</div>

.centrar-form{
 margin: 50px auto;
 float:none;
}
```

además te recomiendo que trabajes con bootstrap y que al  le pongas una clase o un style con resize:none queda más bonito y estilizado. (en bootstrap tienes clases predefinidas para todo tipo de elementos, como por ejemplo para los inputs tienes la clase form-control que te deja los inputs bien bonitos)

Answer (score 0):

Para centrar los elementos de tu formulario (`inputs` y `labels`) puedes usar `text-align: center` como te han comentado anteriormente.

Sin embargo, ya que estás usando `Bootstrap` también puedes usar la clase predefinida por `Bootstrap` llamada `text-center` directamente sobre el formulario.

```
<form id="formulario" action="enviado.php" method="post" class="text-center">
```

Realmente puedes usar `text-align: center` o `text-center` sobre los `inputs` y las `label` debido a que tienen por defecto la propiedad `display: inline` lo que hace que sean tratados como si fueran texto y por tanto que se puedan centrar.

Si los elementos que contuviera el formulario tuvieran, en su defecto, la propiedad `display: block`, no se centrarían con las propiedades nombradas anteriormente.

Además, deberías eliminar la propiedad `align-content: center;` de tu CSS ya que sólo tendría efecto si hubieras puesto la propiedad `display: flex` (flexbox) al formulario.

Tu ejemplo corregido:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border:none;
    width: 100%;
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#formulario{
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    width: 500px;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 14px;
}

input {
    font-size: 14px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #777;
    max-width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    padding: 7px 8px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    background: #0088B2;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

textarea{
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #777;
    max-width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    padding: 7px 8px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <object id="header" data="header.html" onload="resizeObj(this);"></object>

            <form id="formulario" action="enviado.php" method="post" class="text-center">
                <div id="content">
                    <label>Nombre</label><br>
                    <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" /> <br>
                    <label>Email</label><br>
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" /> <br>
                    <label>Contenido</label><br>
                    <textarea id="contenido" name="comment" cols="30" rows="5">Ingresa aqui el mensaje...</textarea><br>

                    <input id="campo3" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
                </div>
            </form>

     <object id="footer" data="footer.html" onload="resizeObj(this);" ></object>
</body>
```